# Can pilots wear glasses/corrective lenses inside the cockpit?

Tags: pilots, medical

I was wondering If I could wear corrective lenses/glasses inside the cockpit If I have a certified class 2 medical certificate?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: Not only can they, but they must if it is required by their medical certificate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  All current classes of FAA-issued medical certificates allow for the use of corrective lenses in the cockpit.  See Title 14 §67 Medical Standards and Certification.

Answer (score 2):

According [to the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/), yes. For a Class 2 Medical:

> - Distant Vision: 20/20 or better in each eye separately, with or without correction.
> - Near Vision:  20/40 or better in each eye separately (Snellen equivalent), with or without correction, as measured at 16 inches.
> - Intermediate Vision:  20/40 or better in each eye separately (Snellen equivalent), with or without correction at age 50 and over, as measured at 32 inches.

Notice the "with or without correction".

Answer (score 1):

According to the CAA in the [UK](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Medical-standards/Pilots-(EASA)/Conditions/Visual/Visual-system-guidance-material-GM/),

```
Class 1
Refractive error

(1) At initial examination an applicant may be assessed as fit with:

  (i) hypermetropia not exceeding +5.0 dioptres;

  (ii) myopia not exceeding -6.0 dioptres;

  (iii) astigmatism not exceeding 2.0 dioptres;

  (iv) anisometropia not exceeding 2.0 dioptres;
```

provided that optimal correction has been considered and no significant pathology is demonstrated.

BUT there are a long list of exceptions and further conditions that may well disqualify you anyway.
And the requirements for a class 2 medical are stricter, add limits on top of this.

Comment: Hey - I'm not sure if it's the other way round in the USA, but in the UK Class 1 is the strict, commercial medical and Class 2 is what you need for a PPL and a lot less strict.